# Trouble changing scope with react-oauth/google

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

My web app use react-oauth/google's implicit flow as a way to obtain authorization to GoogleAPI in order to use DriveAPI/GooglePickerAPI. I have configured drive as a scope in consent screen, however, when signing in with react-oauth what returned is a different scope from what i have configured.

my code for authorization using react-oauth/google's implicit flow

```
const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    // scope: "https.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    onSuccess: async (codeResponse) => {
      console.log(codeResponse);
      Cookies.set("access_token", codeResponse.access_token);
      console.log(Cookies.get("access_token"));
      loginWithGoogle(codeResponse.access_token).then((res) => {
        const temp = {
          ...res.data.data,
          ...res.data.user_info,
        };
        console.log(temp);
        Cookies.set("account", JSON.stringify(temp));
        console.log(JSON.parse(Cookies.get("account")));
        dispatch(login());
      });
    },
    onError: (errorResponse) => console.log(errorResponse),
  });
```

what google return:

```
access_token: "ya29.a0AfB_byDLIGIfeFRCq6-mmAgmUfV6V..."
​
authuser: "0"
​
expires_in: 3599
​
prompt: "none"
​
scope: "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
​
token_type: "Bearer"
```

[image: My scope configuration]

I would greatly aprreciate your help! Advices on other approachs would also be welcomed.

What i tried: adding scope: "https.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly", . However, i got an error saying: "some requesteds scope are invalid"